# Check an array value is string or number in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to check whether an array contains string values or number values.I check with the below code in javascript . But code below is not working.

```
$(function() {
    var data = ["0", "1", "2"];
var isAlpha = false;
var alphabetRegex = /^[a-zA-Z]*$/; ///^[a-zA-Z ]*$/
arrayLen = data.length;
//checking if array is alphabet
while (--arrayLen) {
    if (alphabetRegex.test(data[arrayLen])) {
        isAlpha = true;
        break;
    }
}

if (isAlpha == true) { //this condition for alphabet sorting
    //......code here
} else { //this condition only for number values
    //code here
}

});
```

Comment: Do you want to check only string and only numbers or alphanumeric?

Comment: You want to check if all the values are `string` or `number`?

Comment: need to check numeric or string.If alphanumeric is there,required result is string

Comment: Basically, you just need to check if the array contains an alphabet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code is working for me.
I have changed the if condition as

```
if (data[arrayLen].trim().match(/\D/)) {
```

instead of

```
if (alphabetRegex.test(data[arrayLen]))
```

Complete Code:

```
$(function() {
var data = ["0", "1", "2"];
var isAlpha = false;
arrayLen = data.length;
//checking if array is alphabet
while (--arrayLen) {
    if (data[arrayLen].trim().match(/\D/)) {
        isAlpha = true;
        break; //break the loop if even single array value contains string
    }
}

if (isAlpha == true) { //this condition for alphabet sorting
    //......code here
} else { //this condition only for number values
    //code here
}
});
```

Comment: It's good thing that you've got answer, but explain what you've changed and why it is working now

Comment: You should add this in answer, not in comments. BTW, welcome to SO!